# Add special price and discount amount to the catergory page

Tags: php, magento

hello I am trying to display the special price and discount percentage to the category page products. I have managed to do it on the actual product view but it still displays just the base price on the category page so without clicking into the product the user would not be aware a different price exists. I have added the following code to this file:

app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/price

above this

```
<?php // Display Discount percents start ?>
<?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
<?php $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100); ?>
    <p class="special-price yoursaving">
        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Your Saving:') ?></span>
        <span class="price">
            <?php echo $_savingPercent; ?>%
        </span>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It works nicely for the product page view but i just need to figure how to display on the category pages with the special price also shown.

Any help appreciated thanks!

Comment: The code above is working fine for the product page but i cant get it display on the category view

Comment: You did not answer the question: you should provide the code you have tried, and tell us what error message or wrong output you get, and what output you want, with clear examples. With what you provided we cannot see how your variables get their values, the loop-context in which this code runs, ... etc.